# How to find the distance between two patches?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to have agents go the most efficient possible route to their destination (randomly selected from a patchset of 10 patches). The problem is, distance seems to be an agent-only command, and the only code I've found that does anything similar seems to work by running the distance command with patches, which gives an error.

This is the troublesome procedure:

```
to-report best-route

  let visible-patches patches in-radius turtles-vision-dist

 let visible-routes visible-patches with [ pcolor = gray ]

  let routes-that-take-me-closer visible-routes with [

    ;;THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE RIGHT BELOW HERE

    [ distance visible-routes] of destination < [ distance destination - 1 ] of myself
  ]
```

In the example I had found, Paths, this was the code:

```
to-report best-way-to [ destination ]

  let visible-patches patches in-radius walker-vision-dist

  let visible-routes visible-patches with [ pcolor = gray ]

  let routes-that-take-me-closer visible-routes with [

    distance destination < [ distance destination - 1 ] of myself
  ]

  ifelse any? routes-that-take-me-closer [

    ; from those route patches, choose the one that is the closest to me

    report min-one-of routes-that-take-me-closer [ distance self ]
  ] [

    ; if there are no nearby routes to my destination
    report destination
  ]

end
```

I had originally had something more similar, but it wasn't working, so I've been playing around with it with no luck, as have a classmate and my professor.

Comment: I'm currently working on trying to create a teachers breed to use links, which could potentially circumvent the distance-being-a-turtle-only-command problem, but so far it hasn't worked out. Maybe it will eventually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure out how your paths algorithm is supposed to work since it doesn't look like you are restricting movement to grey patches. However, assuming your destination is stored as a patch, then you can can calculate distance to that patch directly with `distance destination`, like this:

```
turtles-own [ destination ]

to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1
  [ set destination one-of patches
    ask destination [ set pcolor blue ]
  ]
  ask one-of turtles
  [ print distance destination
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I don't think that part actually works yet, but it's sort of there. That line should help a lot! It should let me do the distance part, and then I'll just work out the facing-patches part. Thank you!

Comment: I think instead of `distancexy ...` you can just do `distance destination`.

Comment: @SethTisue you can - I will edit my answer. No idea why I went down the distancexy path